# Network Connection problem just after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, internet

I was using Windows 7 and I decided to give a shot to Ubuntu. So I installed it via usb. However after installing I cannot see any connections. Please help me!!!

Comment: What type of connection do you want to have? Go to Settings -> Network and you can setup connections there.

Comment: When I installed 16.04 my wireless was hard-switched off (`RFKILL`ed) by default for some reason. If you have a **Fn** command or a wifi switch, try that, and also run `ifconfig` to make sure your adapter is recognized now. Also run `rfkill list all` to see if it made its way to that list for any reason.